# What I am getting " $ is not a function " error message in console log ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do smooth scrolling effect using jQuery but in console it's showing me following error message :

> main.js:253 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>       at main.js:253

JQuery code I am using :

```
(function($) {

   $('#what, .down').click(function() {
      e.preventDefault();
      var target= $(this).get(0).id == 'what' ? $('.down') : $('#what');
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
  });   

})(jQuery);
```

Is there anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: make sure u include jquery lib in the html file

Comment: Have you included jquery library in the head tag?

Comment: Yes I did it in html head section.

Comment: Include `jquery` lib properly

Comment: try removing `$` from `function($)`

Comment: is it your document.ready ??

Comment: Make sure jquery is the first file you enter and there should be NO jquery code before your include of jquery and also its `$(function(){})`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande I am trying to delete it.

Comment: Use like following

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// jQuery code is in here

});`

Comment: May be because of an older version of Jquery, Update your jquery for a newer version and try

Comment: Include jquery file before your main.js

Comment: have you checked in the console / network tabs in the developer tools console to make sure that the jquery library loads - no errors? are you perhaps adding defer attribute to the script tag that loads jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Error

> $ is not a function at main.js

**Assuming** that you checked that jquery library is loading without an issue using the console / network tabs in the developer tools

**Solution 1**
Possibly could be because of an external javascript was loaded first before the jquery was loaded. To solve this use `requirejs`, follow this link for the usage http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

**Solution 2**
Update the Jquery Version your using, may be your using an older version

**Soluton 3**

Use it like this in a JS file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// jQuery code is in here

});
```

After declaring like this you will be able to access `$`

Answer (score 1):

The error

> $ is not a function at main.js

Indicates that your jQuery is not properly included in your document. Make sure:

- jQuery is added in the header as first file before any other custom scripts

Example:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make Sure you have included the Javascript Library file in the head.
- Make Sure the Javascript Library file is being loaded before any of the other JS file, In your case `Main.js`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because you haven't added jQuery library file. 
You can call library file using CDN(Content Delivery Network) also or you can download library file and call jquery library before your main.js

Comment: `This error is coming because you haven't added jQuery library file` - did you read the OP's comment, 20 minutes before you posted this (non) answer `Yes I did it in html head section`